# Problem with page loading content, inside content

Tags: php, jquery, pageload

if you visit here: [Example](http://goo.gl/K3rcR) You will see my problem.

The page loads, then loads all the same content within a div id=`content`

Have a look at the source for the JS/jQuery and if you need the PHP just let me know. Im not too sure if its the JS or PHP that's doing this. I use the [jQuery Address Plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) so maybe im not using it properly but this is killing me.

any ideas on what i could be doing wrong? in Firebug the page loads and simply doesn't stop. Try it out if you have it.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line of code:

```
$('.content').load('http://laynestaley.co.uk/test/'+fragment+'?ajax=1');
```

Is actually loading the entire page into `<div class='content'></div>`. Your server-side code must not be executing the way you expect it to with that AJAX call (It's just loading the index page of `/test/` again).

Comment: thanks!! now i can focus on what is happening! is there any way you can help me with PHP? im useless when it comes to it

Comment: @Ricki: I'm useless when it comes to PHP as well :P. It might be easiest to open a new question.

Comment: no problem, thanks for pointing this out. had a sneaking suspicion this was to blame. now to make it right!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Andrew, but just a suggestion -- if you don't want the page to "snap" when the AJAX is loaded, set your height in css to something like 100%

Comment: yep. if the height after the content is loaded is something like 400px, set the content div to 400px, then when the content loads, it won't snap.

Comment: thanks man, i may use an effect for content load, not sure how yet but i'll get there

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly building `fragment`. In you code first letter truncated in query.

Correct code:

```
fragment = event.value.substring(2);
```