# help with PHP and JavaScript code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, incompatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with page loading content, inside content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391244/problem-with-page-loading-content-inside-content)

so im having problems, the two pieces of code i will reprint worked fine until is introduced a jQuery plugin. Firstly the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.address.crawlable(true).init(function(event) {
                $('.nav a').address();
            }).change(function(event) {
                $('.nav a').each(function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected', $(this).attr('href') == '#!' + event.value);
                });
               fragment = event.value.slice(1).replace('!', '');
        $('.content').load('http://mysite.com/test/'+fragment+'?ajax=1');


            });
    });
```

And now the PHP:

```
<?php

$base = 'http://mysite.com/test';

include('data.php');

if ($fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_']) {
    // OPTION 1: if Google is reqesting an '_escaped_fragment_=' page, then redirect to a clean URL
    header("Location: $base/$fragment", 1, 301);
    exit;
}

if ($_GET['url']){
    // If there's a URL parameter, then load the data.
    $data = loaddata($_GET['url']);
    if ($_GET['ajax'] == 1){
        // OPTION 2: If the user's browser is requesting just the data (as an AJAX request), that's all we'll return
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $data = '<p>Select a link from above to get started :)</p>';
}

//OPTION 3: a user or bot is requesting an HTML page, and we're return that to them now.


?>
```

Whats happening is visible here: http://laynestaley.co.uk/test/

The page load is fired and then constantly fired over and over, loading the `test` index into a div with class `content`.

Why do these two samples not work together?

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Comment: I don't see anything going wrong on that page :/

Comment: highlight the content inside the white div, youll see the page inside the div, just with white writing

Comment: well sort of.. i wanted to know why the PHP isnt working correctly and decided to open up another topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root page is loading itself into the div.

In a quick and dirty way, you could just check to make sure

```
if (document.url != 'http://laynestaley.co.uk/test/#!/') {
    $('.content').load('http://mysite.com/test/'+fragment+'?ajax=1');
}
```

Comment: thakns, i cant fully understand this tough, simply put this line before my call?? or use an `if()` function

Comment: Yeah, in your Javascript you need to check what the url is so it doesn't load the root page into $('.content').

Check the updated answer.